# Value error when plotting Dataframe from index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is of the following structure:

```
A          B
Location1  1
Location2  2
1          3
2          4
```

In the above example column A is the index. I am attempting to produce a scatter plot using the index and column B. This data frame is made by resampling and averaging another dataframe like so:

```
df = df.groupby("A").mean()
```

Now obviously this sets the index equal to column A and I can plot it using the following which is adapted from here. [Use index in pandas to plot data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084487/use-index-in-pandas-to-plot-data)

```
df.reset_index().plot(x = "A",y = "B",kind="scatter", figsize=(10,10))
```

Now when I run this it returns the follow:

```
ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric
```

As the index column is intended to be a column of strings for which I can plot a scatter plot how can I go about fixing this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you have strings like 'Location1' in col A then how do you expect them to be plotted?

Comment: Just as a standard scatter plot with the values in A on the x and B values on the Y.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to select only the integer rows:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': ["Location1", "Location2", 1, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_numeric = df[pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').notnull()]

print(df_numeric)

   A  B
2  1  3
3  2  4
```

Grouped by A:

```
df_numeric_grouped_by_A = df_numeric.groupby("A").mean()

print(df_numeric_grouped_by_A)

   B
A   
1  3
2  4
```

Comment: Whilst this is valid on it's own, it's not what I'm looking for. I need to have the Location1 and Location2 strings as x values which can be plotted.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to transponse the DataFrame, so that you have the index(Column A) as columnnames and then calculate the mean of the columns and plot them.