# Scatter plot form dataframe with index on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got pandas `DataFrame`, `df`, with `index` named `date` and the columns `columnA`, `columnB` and `columnC`

I am trying to scatter plot `index` on a x-axis and `columnA` on a y-axis using the `DataFrame` syntax.

When I try:

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='date', y='columnA')
```

I ma getting an error `KeyError: 'date'` probably because the `date` is not column

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', y='columnA')
```

I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: scatter requires and x and y column
```

so no default index on x-axis.

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x=df.index, y='columnA')
```

I am getting error

```
KeyError: "DatetimeIndex(['1818-01-01', '1818-01-02', '1818-01-03', '1818-01-04',\n
                          '1818-01-05', '1818-01-06', '1818-01-07', '1818-01-08',\n
                          '1818-01-09', '1818-01-10',\n               ...\n  
                          '2018-03-22', '2018-03-23', '2018-03-24', '2018-03-25',\n
                          '2018-03-26', '2018-03-27', '2018-03-28', '2018-03-29',\n 
                          '2018-03-30', '2018-03-31'],\n  
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=73139, freq=None) not in index"
```

---

I can plot it if I use `matplotlib.pyplot` directly

```
plt.scatter(df.index, df['columnA'])
```

**Is there a way to plot index as `x-axis` using the `DataFrame` `kind` syntax?**

Comment: check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39536653/13286624

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is kind of ugly (I think the matplotlib solution you used in your question is better, FWIW), but you can always create a temporary DataFrame with the index as a column usinng

```
df.reset_index()
```

If the index was nameless, the default name will be `'index'`. Assuming this is the case, you could use

```
df.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y='columnA')
```

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I think I know why it is not possible out of the box. I doesn't make much sense to do the scatter plot with `index` as the index should be unique. In my case it would be better to use bins.

Comment: @Kocur4d Thanks. Just an FYI: index does *not* have to be unique: `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]}, index=[1, 1])` is fine. I suspect the lack of support for scatters on index in Pandas is more of an oversight.

Answer (score 10):

At least in `pandas>1.4` whats easiest is this:

```py
df['columnA'].plot(style=".")
```

This lets you mix scatter and line plots, as well as use the  standard pandas plot interface

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the correct as it doesn't require any augmentation of the original data frame.

Comment: A line plot does not have some of the scatter plot options like coloring individual points.

Answer (score 9):

A more simple solution would be:

```
df['x1'] = df.index
```

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x1', y='columnA')
```

Just create the index variable outside of the plot statement.

Comment: I sat `x=df.index` directly, so I could get rid of an error this solution provides. But for the most part, I found this answer to be correct.

Comment: Yeah, as I come back and look at this. I agree `df.plot(kind='scatter', x=df.index, y='columnA')` is better.

Comment: Hmm,  `df.plot(kind='scatter', x=df.index, y='columnA')` gives me an error:
`raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: 'None of [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)] are in the [columns]'`