# Plotting a Line Plot in Pandas on a double-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, indexing

I have a dataframe as shown below with double index 'month' and 'day'

```
    query_sorted_gross = '''
    SELECT days.Gross, days.month, days.day
    FROM days, horror_movies
    WHERE horror_movies."Movie ID" = days."Movie ID"

'''
df_q1 = pd.read_sql_query(query_sorted_gross, conn)
df_q1_grouped = df_q1.groupby(['month', 'day']).mean()
```

I want to create a line plot that shows date on the X-axis and Gross on the Y-axis. How do I plot a double-indexed dataframe with a line plot.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834883/scatter-plot-form-dataframe-with-index-on-x-axis

Comment: @Julia that did not work for my case, thanks for the link however.