# How to make a scatter plot over index as x value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot, scatter

I have the following data in dataframe :

```
High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   year    pct_day
Date    month   week    day                             
1989-01-03  1   1   3   277.720001  273.809998  277.720001  275.309998  128500000   275.309998  1989    NaN
1989-01-04  1   1   4   279.750000  275.309998  275.309998  279.429993  149700000   279.429993  1989    0.014965
1989-01-05  1   1   5   281.510010  279.429993  279.429993  280.010010  174040000   280.010010  1989    0.002076
1989-01-06  1   1   6   282.059998  280.010010  280.010010  280.670013  161330000   280.670013  1989    0.002357
1989-01-09  1   2   9   281.890015  280.320007  280.670013  280.980011  163180000   280.980011  1989    0.001104
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2006-12-22  12  51  22  1418.819946 1410.280029 1418.099976 1410.760010 1647590000  1410.760010 2006    -0.005316
2006-12-26  12  52  26  1417.910034 1410.449951 1410.750000 1416.900024 1310310000  1416.900024 2006    0.004352
2006-12-27  12  52  27  1427.719971 1416.630005 1416.630005 1426.839966 1667370000  1426.839966 2006    0.007015
2006-12-28  12  52  28  1427.260010 1422.050049 1426.770020 1424.729980 1508570000  1424.729980 2006    -0.001479
2006-12-29  12  52  29  1427.000000 1416.839966 1424.709961 1418.300049 1678200000  1418.300049 2006    -0.004513
4539 rows × 8 columns
```

The index value is Date, month, week and day. 
From what i understand you cannot create a scatter plot over x being an index value : a similar question was answered here [StackOverFlow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834883/scatter-plot-form-dataframe-with-index-on-x-axis)
I tried :

```
df.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='Date', y='cumsum_pct_day')
```

but i get `KeyError: 'Date``

This method did work in the link but I am not sure why it is not working here.

This same scatterplot does work with i plot use the following code though:

```
df.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='month', y='cumsum_pct_day')
```

Both month and Date are index values. There is no reason for me to plot scatter over date but for academic reasons i just want to know

Comment: What is `print (df.reset_index().columns)` ?

Comment: `Index(['month', 'day', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close',
       'year', 'pct_day', 'cumsum_pct_day'],
      dtype='object')` Odd Date is not showing.

Comment: so `df.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='month', y='cumsum_pct_day')` not working? there is error?

Comment: Does work on month but not on Date and i am not sure why Date did not show up. Thanks I can take it from here

Comment: It is weird, if use `df = df.reset_index()` amd then `print (df)` then still not datetimes?

Comment: My bad there was this snippit which was causing the problem: `df = data.groupby(['month', 'day']).mean()`

Comment: yop, I was surprise it was magically disappear ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad there was this snippit which was causing the problem: `df = data.groupby(['month', 'day']).mean()`