# Removing Row Indices and Reverting them to a Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following.

[image]

I would like to create a bar chart; however, I can't because `LotType` isn't seen as a column variable name but rather a row header. How can I make `LotType` just like the other columns? I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I haven't been able to find the answer to it.

```
bigdf.plot.bar(x='LotType', y='Ratio2015', figsize=(20, 3), color='maroon')
```

For reference, here is the error I get which I kind of explained above:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
...
KeyError: 'LotType'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scatter plot form dataframe with index on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834883/scatter-plot-form-dataframe-with-index-on-x-axis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to reset_index method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

df.reset_index() will create a new index column with just numbers, and your LotType column will be saved as a normal column.