# Dataframe value.counts() to barplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have a dataframe with multiple columns such as product name, reviews, origin, and etc.
Here, I want to create a barplot with only the data from "Origin" column.

To do this, I used the code:
`origin = df['Origin'].value_counts()`

With this, I was able to get a list of countries with corresponding frequencies (or counts). Now, I want to create a boxplot with each country on X-axis and counted frequencies on the Y-axis. Although the column for frequencies have a column label, I am unable to set the X-axis as the countries are merely saved as index. Would there be a better way to count the column "Origin" and make it into a barplot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean a `barplot`? You can't compute a `boxplot` on already aggregated data. Try `df['Origin'].value_counts().plot.bar()`

Comment: @mozway oops I mean barplot. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use index in pandas to plot data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084487/use-index-in-pandas-to-plot-data)